# What's the best practice to create a Spring Search Form?

Tags: spring, search, spring-mvc

What's the best practice to create a Spring MVC Search Form?

As example could be search a Client by name, lastname and category.

Is neccesary create a class with the same paramaters used in the search form, so then bind that class to the form?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is neccesary create a class with the same paramaters used in the search form, so then bind that class to the form?

This is one way. It is a good way to use this class (CommandObject / FormBackingBean) if you want to have somehow predefined values in the input fields of your serarch form.

If you do not need predefind fields, then the easyest way would be accessing the request parameters "direclty":

```
@RequestMapping("search")
public ModelAndView search(@RequestParam("searchTerm") String searchTerm)
```

Comment: solved by creating a class with the same parameters as the search